# How to iterate an array value to all the elements of another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have 2 arrays: cars & bikes.
I want to compare each element of car array to all the other elements of bike array, If both are equal, then alert true else false.

```
$scope.getComparison = function() {
$scope.bikes = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
angular.forEach($scope.bikes, function(value, key) {
    $scope.p_Id = value.bikes;
    $scope.cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
    angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(value, key) {
        $scope.b_Id = value.cars;
        if ($scope.p_Id == $scope.b_Id) {
            alert(b_Id + "=" + p_Id + "=" + "true");
        } else {
            alert(b_Id + "=" + p_Id + "=" + "false");
        }
    });
  });
};
```

Where am I wrong ? I need help.

Comment: `"value.bikes"` ? Check console for errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
   $scope.bikes = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
   $scope.cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
   angular.forEach($scope.bikes, function(bike) {
      angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(car) {
        if (bike == car) {
          alert(bike + "=" + car + "=" + "true");
         } else {
             alert(bike  + "=" + car+ "=" + "false");
           }
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Not working!**

```
var _firstArray = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
var _secondArray=["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];

var areEqual = true;

_firstArray.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!(item in _secondArray)) {
        areEqual = false;
    }
});
console.log(areEqual);
```

**EDIT**: I was wrong about the "in" operator. It only checks properties for a given object.

`"45" in _firstArray` will result in `false`, but `0 in _firstArray` will result in `true` as `0` is a property for that array, `'length' in _firstArray` will result in `true` as well. Here is a working solution:

```
var _firstArray = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
var _secondArray=["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];

_firstArray.forEach(function(item1) {
    _secondArray.forEach(function (item2) {
        if (item1 === item2) {
            console.log(item1 + '=' + item2 + '=' + 'true');
        } else {
            console.log(item1 + '=' + item2 + '=' + 'false');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` & `indexOf` array methods to find the match

```
var _firstArray = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
var _secondArray=["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
_firstArray.forEach(function(item){
  if (_secondArray.indexOf(item) !==-1){
     console.log(item)  
  }
  else{
  console.log("not matched");
  }
})
```

Note: You can same array methods in your code

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1owo30u/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you're looking for

jsFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25016/ . Replaced alert with console

```
$scope.getComparison = function() {
$scope.bikes = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
angular.forEach($scope.bikes, function(value, key) {
    $scope.p_Id = value;
    $scope.cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
    angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(value, key) {
        $scope.b_Id = value;
        if ($scope.p_Id == $scope.b_Id) {
            alert($scope.b_Id + "=" + $scope.p_Id + "=" + "true");
        } else {
            alert($scope.b_Id + "=" + $scope.p_Id + "=" + "false");
        }
    });
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

value argument of the `forEach()` method already represents the bike in the array as such, same goes for the car:
You can change your code like this:

```
$scope.getComparison = function() {
$scope.bikes = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
angular.forEach($scope.bikes, function(value, key) {
    $scope.p_Id = value;
    $scope.cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
    angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(value, key) {
        $scope.b_Id = value;
        if ($scope.p_Id == $scope.b_Id) {
            alert(b_Id + "=" + p_Id + "=" + "true");
        } else {
            alert(b_Id + "=" + p_Id + "=" + "false");
        }
    });
});
};
```

And it should work.

You can also nest the `forEach()` methods like such:

```
 $scope.getComparison = function() {
    $scope.bikes = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
    $scope.cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
    angular.forEach($scope.bikes, function(bikeValue, bikeKey) {
        angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(carValue, carKey) { 
            if (bikeValue == carValue) {
                alert(bikeValue + "=" + carValue + "=" + "true");
            } else {
                alert(bikeValue + "=" + carValue + "=" + "false");
            }
        });
    });
    };
```

This way directly compare them without saving the values to `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing **each** element of 1 array with **each** element of another array?

2 **each**'s means use 2 loops thats it.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issue with your code, try below code and should work perfectly:

```
$scope.getComparison = function() {
                        $scope.bikes = ["1", "3", "3", "2", "6", "55", "45", "36", "18"];
                        angular.forEach($scope.bikes, function(value, key) {
                            $scope.p_Id = value;
                            $scope.cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "54", "55", "56", "56", "58"];
                            angular.forEach($scope.cars, function(value, key) {
                                $scope.b_Id = value;
                                if ($scope.p_Id == $scope.b_Id) {
                                    alert($scope.b_Id + "=" + $scope.p_Id + "=" + "true");
                                } else {
                                    alert($scope.b_Id + "=" + $scope.p_Id + "=" + "false");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    };
```

Comment: You should probably explain what the issue is.

Comment: Issue was with value.bikes & value.cars, actually we had to refer value not value.bikes since it is nothing. So we have corrected it in the above code added by me.